# How to sort a numeric dimension in ssas

Tags: ssas

In one of my dimensions I have 4 columns with the data type `tinyint` but in ssas after processing the cube, its been assigned the data type `system.byte`. I dont know it did that. And because of this my data sort is like 1, 10, 2 etc. but I want it to be 1, 2, 3 etc. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dimension designer select each  attribute. Then set OrderBy=Key. Redeploy.

Comment: it throws the error: `Error 1 DimensionAttribute [Table].[PDECBIOColumn] : The ordering criteria is set to 'AttributeKey', but the ordering attribute is not set`

Comment: @Faiz oops. Sorry. Edited my answer.

Comment: This does not work, If I read the cube in excel. Is there a way to control the sorting order while viewing a cube in excel?

Comment: @Niraj why don't you start a new question with screenshots of what isn't working. This setting definitely does control the order in Excel so something else must be going on